# Is there something wrong with the insert.php given below?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried hard to debug the following insert.php file. There are no errors while running this and the associated webform file inwamp server, but it is not reading data to the database. Can someone comment on this?

```
?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


//Connect to the database



$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$dbc=mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die("Connection Error");
$db_name="userregistration";
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("Could not select database");



//Reading data from form and writing to the DB
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$institution = $_POST['institute'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$pgm = $_POST['pgm'];
$address = $_POST['address'];



//Examining for input errors
$error = FALSE;


if (isset($address)) {
$address = trim($address);
$address = strip_tags($address);
}

if (isset($fname) && 
isset($institute) && 
isset($email) && 
isset($phone) && 
isset($pgm) &&
isset($address) &&
$error == FALSE) {
$process = TRUE;
} else {
$process = FALSE;
}

//Writing the multiple answers for user selected programs

while ((list($key,$val) = each($pgm))) {
$pgm .= "[" . $val . "]";
}



//Creating the table
$query = "create table userdata
( sid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
fname char(50) not null,
institute char(50) not null,
email char(50) not null,
phone int unsigned,
pgm text not null,
address char(200) not null)";
$q = mysql_query($query);




//Inserting the data
$query = "insert into userdata values ('','$fname','$institute','$email','$phone','$pgm','$address')";
$q = mysql_query($query);


//Check whether data was properly inserted
if (!$q) {
exit("<p>MySQL Insertion failure.</p>");
} else {
mysql_close();
echo "<p>MySQL Insertion Successful</p>";
}

}
?>
```

Can someone comment on this ?

Comment: Don't forget to escape you post variables. Now your code is vulnerable to sql-injects

Comment: And why do you create a table every-time this thing is loaded?

Comment: another remark. You set $error to false and two lines later you check if $error is false, bit strange!

Comment: You've got SQL injection holes, you've got NO database query error handling. Plug the holes, add the error handling, and you'll quickly find out why this isn't working.

Comment: @Tim : I didn't understand what you meant by escaping the POST variable. What is that and how is it done? I will try the CREATE query as SQL command in phpmyadmin, and remove it from this file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity....the form you created, is the submit buttons name set to "submit"?

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

after your mysql_query($query). That will surely show an error if it failed...

Comment: When running the files in Wamp server, what happens is that I get a blank page, with nothing being inserted in the database. Even the table is not being created.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to echo out $q ? it should tell exactly what's wrong when trying to add to database..

Comment: @Andrew De Forest : Can you explain a bit more on the $error issue?

Now, I am at the college. I will post the results once I reach home.

Comment: Thanks to Asaf, Andrew and Tim for the answers. I'm pretty new to php and mysql. Just day before yesterday, did I get my book on these. I wrote the code taking help from some of the online tutorial. I will echo the insert query and check whether an error pops up.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Check whether data was properly inserted
if (!$q) {
die(mysql_error());
exit();
} else {
mysql_close();
echo "<p>MySQL Insertion Successful</p>";
}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong in the above code I have written. To my knowledge, both does the same, except that I have added to Echoes.....

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the table already exists and so when the user submits the form your code is again trying to create the table 'userdata' which is already there and then dies.

You should remove the create statement out of your code because on every submission it's going to try and create a table that already exists.  You should also look about escaping the submtted data before you pass on to an SQL statement as you're just asking for SQL injection attacks as the code stands now.

Comment: Hei Hairzo, after executing the insert.php, the table is not being created. I made it sure by checking the phpmyadmin page.